# Set of all finite unions of left half-open intervals forms a ring

Tags: measure-theory

Let's denote this set by $F$. F is clearly a subset of the set of all left half-open intervals. I'm having a hard time showing this property:

$A,B\in F \Rightarrow A \cup B \in F$

Answer (score 1):

We may assume that $A=(a,b]$ and $(c,d]$. Without loss of generality $a\leq c$
Then $A\cup B=(a,d]$ or $A\cup B=(a,b]\cup (c,d]$, where the latter one is a disjoint union. Both are left half open.